# prestapyt error on edit

Tags: python, api, prestashop

I'm using the prestashop API [`prestapyt`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/prestapyt)

I add a category by hand in my site, but when I'm trying to edit via the API, it fails.
Even the most simple thing, does not work:

```
ps = PrestaShopWebServiceDict(config.DOMAIN, config.KEY)
xml = ps.get('categories', 35)
ps.edit('categories',35,xml)
```

The xml (type DICT) loads ok, but the `.edit()` fails.

Here is the response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noukeys\Documents\psapi\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    ps.edit('categories',35,xml)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prestapyt\prestapyt.py", line 333, in edit
    return self.edit_with_url(full_url, content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prestapyt\prestapyt.py", line 452, in edit_with_url
    return  super(PrestaShopWebServiceDict, self).edit_with_url(url, xml_content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prestapyt\prestapyt.py", line 344, in edit_with_url
    return self._parse(self._execute(url, 'PUT', body=unicode_encode.encode(content), add_headers=headers)[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prestapyt\prestapyt.py", line 171, in _execute
    self._check_status_code(status_code)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prestapyt\prestapyt.py", line 125, in _check_status_code
    % (status_code, message_by_code[status_code]), status_code)
prestapyt.prestapyt.PrestaShopWebServiceError: 'This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means: Bad Request.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues with edits also, but I am getting a 501 error.  Turns out my host does not allow PUT requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on debugging in the api.

```
prestashop.debug = True
```

And then turn on display_errors in config.inc.php for your shop.  This helped me debug why the request was bad.  The error messages are pretty clear.

Comment: In which file should the line `prestashop.debug = True` be added? In OpenERP configuration or in prestashop configuration?

Comment: @psychoslave This goes in the python script where you are trying to use the function `prestashop.edit()`